# calling javascript in ajax validation

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two password entry input fields:

```
<input class="form-control" type="password" name=password placeholder="Password"/>
```

and

```
<input class="form-control" type="password" id="button" placeholder="Confirm Password" onblur=";"/>
```

I want to validate the passwords are identical using ajax, if they aren't display an error directly bellow the input fields, if not I want to call a javascript function that will generate the hash for the password( I have a javascript function prepared for that, I just need the function called)

here's what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    $("#create_user").click(function(e)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var password = $("#password-input").val(); 
      var password_confirm = $("#password-confirm-input").val();
      if (!password.length || password != password_confirm ) {
        $("#label").html("Passwords do not match");
      }

    }
  });
```

and here's that portion of my html code:

```
<form id="myform" action="add_user.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password-input" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password-confirm-input" placeholder="Confirm Password" onblur=";"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="User Type"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="msg">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name=email placeholder="E-mail Address"/>
          <label id="label" for="male">Male</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
          <input class="btn btn-success" id="create_user" value="Create User"/>
          <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="create_user2" value="Create User"/>
        </div>
```

this code does no validation

Comment: please provide any errors that are occurring. (F12). If there are no errors, step through the code to see where it is stopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you need ajax to compare the passwords. You may do that in javascript.

Assuming `password` and `password2` are the Id values of the textboxes and `save` is the Id value of the button, clicking on which will fire the comparison.

```
$(function(){

  $("#save").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var p1=$("#password").val();
    var p2=$("#password2").val();
    $("#msg").html("");
    if(p1!==p2)
    {
        $("#msg").html("Passwords do not match");
    }     
  });      

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/mixeze/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

---

EDIT : *As per the comment of OP*

The reason your validation is not firing is because of 2 issues.

1) The jquery click event is registered to an element with id `create_user` (`#create_user`), But in your HTML markup your button's id is `create_user2`

2) You have a syntax error here. You are closing the function(after `e`) which you should not.

```
$("#create_user").click(function(e)) {
```

So the solution is to correct your js code to use the correct button id and fix the syntax error.

```
$(function(){      

   $("#create_user2").click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      var password = $("#password-input").val(); 
      var password_confirm = $("#password-confirm-input").val();

      $("#label").html("");
      if (!password.length || password != password_confirm ) {
        $("#label").html("Passwords do not match");
      }

    });      

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/hehapug/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample for that.

Comment: @AdelAhmed Your code has syntax errors. See my updated answer.

Comment: yup it's working, but I'm unable to sumbit now :(
any fix for that?

Comment: Call `$("#YourFormId").submit()` at the end after validation is done